# JavaScript Moveable Divs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make some funny movable divs.
I have the following codes:

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("draggable_shortcut"));
        function dragElement(elmnt) {
          var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
          if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "top-content")) {
            /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
            document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "top-content").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
          } else {
            /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
            elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
          }

          function dragMouseDown(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault();
            // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
            pos3 = e.clientX;
            pos4 = e.clientY;
            document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
            // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
            document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
          }

          function elementDrag(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault();
            // calculate the new cursor position:
            pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
            pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
            pos3 = e.clientX;
            pos4 = e.clientY;
            // set the element's new position:
            elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
            elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
          }

          function closeDragElement() {
            /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
            document.onmouseup = null;
            document.onmousemove = null;
          }
        }
```

```css
#draggable_shortcut {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: grab;
}
#draggable_shortcut img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
#draggable_shortcut p {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable_shortcut">
<img src="https://images.ecosia.org/F9NhZWwmi8VL4EI6ylXOrAhWob4=/0x390/smart/https%3A%2F%2Fmaxcdn.icons8.com%2FShare%2Ficon%2Fultraviolet%2FVery_Basic%2Fidea1600.png">
<p>Moveable Icon</p>
</div>
```

It works really god without issues.
If I add some more divs, the script doesn't work anymore,
because it's just for one and not more.
But I want to make more than one div, which are movable.

I'm new in JavaScript Programming. Any ideas?

---

Thank you for the ideas and scripts.
Not my last question about this script:
Is it possible to make, if the user drops an div, the position should be setted on hundred px?
For example, if the user drops the div on the coordinates (120/105) it should get moved to  (100/100). Another exmaple: (170/355) -> (200/400). 
If possible, would be nice if an user can change, he would want with the hundred corrds or cutsom like this before.

**Update 12.11.2018:**
I found now a possibility to check the coords. But it will be only placed if the coords are exaclty 100 and not like 105. Any ideas? Demo here:
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/fBWlF0B3t4XbjuSW

**Update 12.11.2018 Later...**

I found now a possibillity. For these, who want the same: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/fBWlF0B3t4XbjuSW

Comment: Javascript != Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with *class* instead of *id*.

You have to call the function for each element individually. You can use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
 to get a static (not live) *NodeList* representing a list of the document's elements. Then use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to call the function for each element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".draggable_shortcut").forEach(function(el){
  dragElement(el);
});

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "top-content")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "top-content").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.draggable_shortcut {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: grab;
}
.draggable_shortcut img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.draggable_shortcut p {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable_shortcut">
<img src="https://images.ecosia.org/F9NhZWwmi8VL4EI6ylXOrAhWob4=/0x390/smart/https%3A%2F%2Fmaxcdn.icons8.com%2FShare%2Ficon%2Fultraviolet%2FVery_Basic%2Fidea1600.png">
<p>Moveable Icon</p>
</div>

<div class="draggable_shortcut">
<img src="https://images.ecosia.org/F9NhZWwmi8VL4EI6ylXOrAhWob4=/0x390/smart/https%3A%2F%2Fmaxcdn.icons8.com%2FShare%2Ficon%2Fultraviolet%2FVery_Basic%2Fidea1600.png">
<p>Moveable Icon</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make loop for each item.

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("drag");
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        console.log(elements[i].id)
        dragElement(document.getElementById(elements[i].id));
            function dragElement(elmnt) {
              var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
              if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "top-content")) {
                /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
                document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "top-content").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
              } else {
                /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
                elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
              }

              function dragMouseDown(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                e.preventDefault();
                // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
                pos3 = e.clientX;
                pos4 = e.clientY;
                document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
                // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
                document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
              }

              function elementDrag(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                e.preventDefault();
                // calculate the new cursor position:
                pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
                pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
                pos3 = e.clientX;
                pos4 = e.clientY;
                // set the element's new position:
                elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
                elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
              }

              function closeDragElement() {
                /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
                document.onmouseup = null;
                document.onmousemove = null;
              }
            }
}
```

Also change `id` to `classes`

```
.drag {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: grab;
}
.drag img {
   width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.drag p {
  color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Now each `div` must have individual `id` and the same `class`

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/R8PUSaxkWebiZoq1XraC?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the tipps.
Exact the thing i needed.
Is there a little possibility to make, that icons can only be on coordinates like 100, 100? For example, if the icon is on 140,100 it will be placed at 100, 100?

Comment: @Manuel Try to add top:50%; left:50%; to .drag class, then your icons will be in the middle of page

Comment: @Manuel if you want your icons to be in a specific position add specific distance from the top left right or bottom, like here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9YDf6DwA7xAAvULSKYhA?p=preview